# Javascript close event for an auth pop that will redirect and close the original popup before

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I am using a thirdparty tool that integrated in my html (PHP) as IFrame solution.  (Recommendation of the manufacturer).

```
<iframe id="theIframe" src="manufacture.com"> </ iframe>
```

A pop-up is built up and redirect to a new popup with the login screen. Anyone has idea, how I get can capture all events from all popup.  I need the reference from the login-screen or the close event of them.

How I can check or capture that this event.

The Iframe-initiated pop will be redirected to a second popup (for whatever reason) and will not bind the second popup to the iframe and will not get to the events.

```
   if (window.attachEvent) {
            window.attachEvent("onmessage", receiveMessage);

        } else {
            console.log("event message added");
            window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
        }


   function receiveMessage(event) {

            //capture the event for closing the second popup
            console.log(event);
          

            alert("User has closed the window in the iFrame");
            //Close iFrame
            var iframe = document.getElementById('theIframe');
            iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you

Comment: thanks for your advice @IgnacioAra

Answer (score 0):

In short, the problem is not really a problem.

There is no solution to this problem. I integrated the url of the second pop directly into the iframe. Sometimes the solution is so close.

Sometimes it just helps to rethink the problem.